# Cannot find "Timed publishing" feature in new google play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

google is ready with revamped google play console. but its help & support section is still yet to update. with the deadline to sunset old console. i need to get myself familiar with the console and still cannot figure out how to make timed release .

tried searching in Store listing and Pricing & distribution. but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As per google developer's article:**

Easier publishing
We've renamed Timed Publishing to Managed Publishing. Use it to see a summary of your changes that are in review and control when to publish on Google Play. Managed Publishing also helps you understand all the changes that have been submitted across your releases, store listings, and more. For those of you with larger teams, you can now review and coordinate all your changes in one place so everything is published at the same time.

**For reference:**
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/introducing-new-google-play-console-beta.html